# Menu for a game in Java

Tags: java, swing, applet, jtable, jbutton

I am trying to create a simple menu (black background) that has just a simple button in the middle of the screen that says "Play!", and then when the user clicks that button it would start the game. Now I am not going to copy and paste all of my game code in this, but I will give the starting part that extends the applet that I am using. Here is that code:

```
public class Game extends JApplet implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
AnimateSprite user;
AnimateSprite monster, troll;
Coins ten, twenty;
Thread thread;
Random r;
public void init()
{
    r = new Random();
    user = new AnimateSprite();
    user.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "player.gif"));
    user.setLocation(0, 0);
    monster = new AnimateSprite();
    monster.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "monster.gif"));
    monster.setLocation(100, 100);
    troll = new AnimateSprite();
    troll.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "monster.gif"));
    troll.setLocation(350, 350);
    setupCoins();
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
public void setupCoins()
{
    ten = new Coins(10);
    twenty = new Coins(20);
    ten.setLocation(400, 350);
    twenty.setLocation(450, 50);
    ten.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "coins.gif"));
    twenty.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "coins.gif"));
}
```

All I am trying to do is use/create a simple interface for the user where all they do is just click the "Play!" button and then it would start the game just as it would if I were to run the applet separately. My question is how the best way to go about doing this would be. Any help is greatly appreciated! Also I will add more code to this if the need arises.

Comment: Your "question" is not a question. It's a problem because you should ask questions and we should answer them. Without the question we can't answer. So, ask something and we'll answer.

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I am a little sick of having to use applets, and my teacher even said how they are barely used in Java, but the class he is teaching is an intro to Java through the use of applets.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Joption {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
final JFrame f = new JFrame("The Frame");
   f.setSize(300, 300);
   Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   int width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
   int height = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
   f.setLocation((int)(width/4.5), (int)(height/3.5));
   JButton play=new JButton("play");
   play.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           System.out.print("your code/start meathod goes here");
           f.dispose();
       }});
   f.add(play);
   f.setVisible(true);
   }

}
```

I don't really understand your code so I cant do any better than this well maybe I could make the button look better but you get the idea.

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.JApplet;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;


    public class Jap extends JApplet {
    /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void init(){
    //    r = new Random();
    //    user = new AnimateSprite();
    //    user.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "player.gif"));
    //    user.setLocation(0, 0);
    //    monster = new AnimateSprite();
    //    monster.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "monster.gif"));
    //    monster.setLocation(100, 100);
    //    troll = new AnimateSprite();
      //troll.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "monster.gif"));
        //troll.setLocation(350, 350);
        //setupCoins();
        setFocusable(true);
        //addKeyListener(this);

        //thread = new Thread(this);
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("The Frame");
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
        int height = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
       f.setLocation((int)(width/4.5), (int)(height/3.5));
       JButton play=new JButton("play");
       play.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.print("your code/start meathod goes here");

                //thread.start(); thread will have to be final to be called here or rename it to something that is final
                f.dispose();
            }});
       f.add(play);
       f.setVisible(true);
     }
      void Start(){

      }
    }
```

like this.

Comment: Understanding the OP's code is the first prerequisite to answering.

Comment: no he asked for a button I gave a button the rest wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the play button within the init method, and have it call a method, you cannot use the start method, that just starts the thread.

For example:

```
public void init(){
    //whatever you want here
    t1 = new Thread(this);
    play = new JButton("Play");
    //setLocation, etc, etc.
    add(play);
    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            remove(play);
            repaint();
            test();
        }
    });
}
public void test(){
    t1.start();
}
public void run(){
    //whatever you want here
}
```

So what happens here is that you have a button, that when pressed, removes itself from the screen, calls `paint` (through repaint) to paint the screen, then calls a side method (cannot be `start`) to start the thread, which would start your animation.

Comment: I will make sure to try this out, it seems like it could be a simple way to add a simple JButton.

Comment: @Fyree don't forget that a JButton can also be labeled with an ImageIcon, so if you want it to look nicer, I'd make an Icon that says "Play" but it's your choice. The text wont scale if you make the button large or anything like that either.

Comment: It compiled correctly, but it goes straight to the game, and does not show the menu with the JButton "play".

Comment: Here is a link to another problem that I am having if you would also like to look at that as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411131/how-to-repaint-over-images-in-java-game.