# How to repaint over images in Java game

Tags: java, graphics, paint, intersection, bluej

Hello everyone I am having trouble with painting over coins that the user intersects with. What I want this code to do is when the user sprite intersects with any of the ten coin images it paints over the coin so that it no longer appears on the screen (also need to add in some kind of counter so that when the user collects all ten coins it will stop the thread, and say "You Win!"). My question is how would I go about doing this because I have tried using repaint() in the if statements, and it is not compiling correctly anymore. Any help on how to paint over the coins, and possibly even add some kind of counter (thinking a for loop would come in handy) would be greatly appreciated! Here is the code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    one.paintComponent(g);
    two.paintComponent(g);
    three.paintComponent(g);
    four.paintComponent(g);
    five.paintComponent(g);
    six.paintComponent(g);
    seven.paintComponent(g);
    eight.paintComponent(g);
    nine.paintComponent(g);
    ten.paintComponent(g);
    monster.setLocation(r.nextInt(10) - 5 + monster.x, r.nextInt(10 - 5 + monster.y));
    monster.paintComponent(g);
    user.paintComponent(g);
    if(user.intersects(one))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(two))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(three))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(four))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(five))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(six))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(seven))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(eight))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(nine))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(ten))
    {
    }
    if(user.intersects(monster))
    {
            g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 35));
            g.drawString("YOU HAVE DIED, YOU LOSE!", 100, 100); //Prints this when you lose
            thread.interrupt(); //Stopping the thread if you die
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should put the coins in a list. Then, if there's an interection, you simply remove the item (coin) of the list. Like this:

```
private List<Coin> coins;

public ClassConstructor() {
    coins = new ArrayList();
    coins.add(new Coin(type value,...)); //this ten times if every Coin is different from other
    //or this if every Coin are same:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        coins.add(new Coin(type value,...));
    }
}

public void update() {
    //whatever
    for (int i = coins.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
        if (user.intersects(coins.get(i))) {
            coins.remove(i);
            //...
        }
    }

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = coins.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
        coins.get(i).paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Now, you shouldnt end a Thread with thread.interrupt(). If that thread is your game loop, you should send a flag that ends the loop. The Thread of you game loop:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) { //boolean running
        update();
        paint(g);
    }}
```

And, finally, your update will be like:

```
public void update() {
    //whatever
    for (int i = coins.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
        if (user.intersects(coins.get(i))) {
            coins.remove(i);
            //...
        }
    }
    if (user.intersects(monster)) {
        youThread.setRunning(false);
        try {
            gameLoopThread.join(); //"wait" until thread ends
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by type value?

Comment: Getting invalid method declaration; return type required at public ClassConstructor(){.

Comment: It's just an example of an entity, it's pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, put `while(true)` within your `Run()` method (you said you were using a thread) and call repaint() within the loop, at the end of the loop (within a try/catch) put something like `//thread//.sleep(allotted time)` This will stop the thread for the set amount of Milliseconds. Within the Javadoc of `repaint()` you'll see that it calls the nearest `paint(Graphics g)` method. By doing this you can access your `paint()` method from wherever you are in your program.

My suggestion to the coin's is make it it's own class. The class would look similar to this:

```
public class Coin{
int x;
int y;
public void Coin(int x, int y, Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Image img1 = (//File Location);
    g2.drawImage(img1, x, y, //this);
    //If you have trouble with the ImageObserver (this part) try //class name of the applet.this
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    g2.finalize();
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}
}
```

After that, in your paint method you could make 10 `Coin` objects and use `g` which you instantiate in the parameters. You could then make an array of `Coin` objects and add 10 `Coin`s that you make in your `paint` method manually (yeah, it's a pain) (you have to make them in paint to pass the Graphics variable)

`Coin[] coins = new Coin[10];`

Is how you make the array, by the way. After you make the array of coin's, then make a `for` loop in your `paint` method. It should look something like this:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++){
            if(coins[i].getX == //user X && coins[i].getY == //user Y){
                    g.clearRect(coins[i].getX, coins[i].getY, //Coin radius, //Coin radius);
            }

        }
```

This will make a clear rectangle be drawn over wherever the Coin is at if the user's X and Y is equal to the Coin's X and Y.

Comment: What am I supposed to put in those commented out parts in the for loop? Also I have a coin gif that I want to use, but if it causes problems I will just draw my own coins (also how am I supposed to add the ten coins?). Also it says cannot find symbol - variable getX.

Comment: To add the 10 coins to the array, you have to do coins[1] = `coin1` and so on. those commented parts are what they say, I'm assuming you have a way to track the user's x and y for example. The Coin diameter is there so you draw a perfectly sized `clearRect` over the coin when the x and y of the user and coin are the same. getX is not a variable, it is a method, and you also have to setX before you use getX. I will post an edit changing that for you though.

Comment: @Fyree Check the edit I made to the `Coin` class, it now sets the X and Y within the constructor so getX will work. You CAN use a Gif, you just need to use drawImage use this link to learn how to do that http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/DrawImage.htm

Comment: @Fyree I will edit the `Coin` class so it looks like that website's drawImage for you, but I will comment it out too, so you gotta put what you want where the comments are

Comment: I tried the changes that you made for getX and getY, and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're using `coinObject.getX` right?

Comment: First are you able to edit the for loop, I am getting really confused. Also I am getting "no suitable method found for drawImage" error when I try to use g2.drawImage above.

Comment: You need to import `java.awt.*` in the coin class, I skipped the imports when copying/pasting the code that I wrote in like 5 minutes. You can edit any of the code, I, obviously, don't know your entire game's code, so I'm giving you rough code that you need to adapt to fit inside your code.

Comment: I already have imported java.awt.*, that is why I am confused.

Comment: Try putting `null` in the last spot, where you should have put a `this` statement. That is the `ImageObserver` and I always have issues with that.

Comment: i switched the this statements to null and it is still not working.

Comment: @Fyree I always have a ton of trouble with drawImage, so that's why I recommended just drawing the circles

Answer (score 0):

This code is taken from my current project (that is working), I tried adjusting it to your project.

```
private void render () {
    BufferStrategy bufferstrategy = getBufferStrategy ();

    if (bufferstrategy == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bufferstrategy.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    paint (g);

    g.dispose();
    bufferstrategy.show();
}
```

`render()` is called from run(), where the `Thread` is.

Let's break it down and see if it can help you.

1. It gets a BufferStrategy for how many images to have ready. It can be set to anything like you like within reason. 2 - 4 will do the trick. One can even work.
2. It sets your current `BufferStrategy` to your `Graphics`.
3. It then fills the screen with the color of white (could be a clear as well).
4. Then it paints all components, in your case it calls `paint (Graphics g)` while in my case it iterates through all drawable objects.
5. It re-renders everything as it now should look.

Hope you take some points out from this.